# packaging scientific project in python

Tags: python, numpy, package, private, anaconda

I am trying to build a package for an apps in python. It uses `sklearn`, `pandas`, `numpy`, `boto` and some other scientific module from `anaconda`. Being very unexperienced with python packaging, I have various questions:

1- I have some confidential files `.py` in my project which I don't want anyone to be able to see. In java I would have defined private files and classes but I am completely lost in python. What is the "good practice" to deal with these private modules? Can anyone link me some tutorial?

2- What is the best way to package my apps? I don't want to publish anything on `Pypi`, I only need it to execute on Google App engine for instance. I tried a standalone package with `PyInstaller` but I could not finish it because of `numpy` and other `scipy` packages which makes it hard. Is there a simple way to package in a private way python projects made with `anaconda`?

3- Since I want to build more apps in a close future, shall I try to make sub-packages in order to use them for other apps?

Comment: What do you mean with confidential or private? Python code is always visible on the machine you install it on.

Comment: If you're already using Anaconda I would suggest looking into building conda packages http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/bpp.html. I have no experience with Google App Engine, there may be specific deploy workflows there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The convention is to lead with a single underscore `_` if something is internal. Note that this is a convention. If someone really wants to use it, they still can. Your code is not strictly confidential.
2. Take a look at http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. You don't need to publish to pypi to create a Python package that uses tools such as `pip`. You can create a project with a `setup.py` file and a `requirements.txt` file and then use `pip` to install your package from wherever you have it (e.g., a local directory or a repository on github). If you take this approach then pip will install all the dependencies you list.
3. If you want to reuse your package, just include it in `requirements.txt` and the `install_requires` parameter in `setup.py` (see http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/). For example, if you install your package with `pip install https://github/myname/mypackage.git` then you could include `https://github/myname/mypackage.git` in your `requirements.txt` file in future projects.

Comment: On item 2, bear in mind that a lot of the scientific modules required can be difficult to install from source using `pip` etc, depending on the platform. That's why I'm suggesting the conda packaging route.